# Python loop does not work accurately and reliably with time.sleep

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, tkinter, while-loop

What would be the best way to run a program once a day.
`time.sleep` is inaccurate on long runs.
I try to get `def send_stock_data (self):` run once a day, for example. `time.sleep` drifts too much for this purpose.
The program reads the excel file and sends the data by e-mail if the column 'Amount' is 0.

```
class progloop():
    def prog_loop (self):
        progress.pack_forget()
        while run_cycle == True:
            get_stock_and_send_mail()
            sleep(48000)
            continue
    def __init__(self):#adds Threading to loop 
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.prog_loop)
        t.start()
```

The above `class` currently handles the loop.

Below is the full script.

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import os
import smtplib
import datetime
import time
import pandas as pds
import traceback
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

from tkinter import BOTTOM,HORIZONTAL, Label, Menu, PhotoImage, messagebox, filedialog, ttk
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep


root = tk.Tk()
sec = 0
action = None
run_cycle = True
stop_cycle = True
today = datetime.now()
clock_time = today.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
date = today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
weekday = datetime.today().strftime('%A')
def on_run():#start send_stock_data loop and timer
    global run_cycle, action
    global action
    string_var.set('Application state: Running')
    run_cycle = True
    if not action:
        timer()
def on_stop():#pause send_stock_data loop and timer
    global run_cycle, action
    string_var.set('Application state: Paused')
    run_cycle = False
    messagebox.showinfo('Attention','Program is paused, press Run to resume execution')
    if action:
        root.after_cancel(action)
        action = None
def Info():#Info btn data
    messagebox.showinfo('Application info','''-The application reads the stock balance from the excel file and sends out e-mail information if the part (s)
        of the warehouse balance has run out of stock within the alarm limit.\n
        -The default path to the excel file is specified in the Windows environment variables as 'FilePath'\n
        -In case of problems contact the author
        \n\nDefault alarm limit = 0 parts in stock
        \n\nDefault Google smtp server:'smtp.gmail.com'\nDefault port: 587 ''')
def write_err_log():#writes an error log with traceback
    traceback_err = traceback.format_exc()
    date_time = [clock_time,date]
    write_log = open("ErrorLog.txt", "a")
    write_log.write(str(date_time)) and write_log.write(str(traceback_err))
    write_log.close()    
#Gui
string_var = tk.StringVar()
string_var.set('Application state: Waiting for commands')       
root.iconbitmap(r'C:\\Users\\Lauri\\Visual_studio\\Bitmap_2.ico')
root.title('Warehouse assistant')
root.geometry('460x360')
root.resizable(False,False)
background_image = PhotoImage(file = r'C:\\Users\\Lauri\\Visual_studio\\BcImage.png')
background_label = tk.Label(image=background_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)   
Label_header = ttk.Label(root, font=('underline', 12),text='Parts balance monitoring application').pack()
Label_start = ttk.Label(root,font=('underline',8), text='Press Run to start the application\nPress Pause to stop the application').pack()
Label_appState = ttk.Label(root, font=('underline', 10),textvariable=string_var).pack()
btnInfo = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Info', width= 15, command = Info).pack()                              
Start_btn = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Run', width= 15, command=lambda:[bar(),progloop(),root.after(1000,on_run())]).pack()        
Stop_btn = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Pause', width= 15, command = on_stop).pack()
exit_btn = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Exit', width= 25, command =lambda:[root.after(1000,),root.destroy()]).pack(side=BOTTOM)
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
contact_num = os.environ.get('Contact_number')
contact_email = os.environ.get('Contact_email')
helpmenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label='Contact', menu=helpmenu)
helpmenu.add_command(label=contact_email)
helpmenu.add_command(label=contact_num)
helpmenu.add_command(label= 'Exit', command=root.destroy)
progress = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient = HORIZONTAL,length = 158, mode = 'determinate')   
def bar():#progressbar
    progress['value'] = 5
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.after(50)
    progress['value'] = 43
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.after(300)
    progress['value'] = 68
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.after(50)
    progress['value'] = 100
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.after(1) 
progress.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    
class get_stock_and_send_mail: #send inventory balance information by email 
    def send_stock_data(self):
            count = 0
            pds.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
            pds.set_option('colheader_justify','left')
            #reads excel file and searches for desired inventory balance value
            while True:
                file = os.environ.get('FilePath')#default path to file specified in the Windows environment variables as 'FilePath'
                try:   
                    dataFrame = pds.read_excel(file)
                    break
                except PermissionError as error:
                    write_err_log()
                    messagebox.showerror(title='error',message= 'Permission Error Permission error has occured during read file?\n\n\n'+str(error)+"'.",
                    detail=traceback.format_exc())    
                except FileNotFoundError as error:
                    messagebox.showwarning(title='Select Excel File',
                    message='DEFAULT FILE NOT FOUND.\nChoose Excel file from directory.\nCONTINUE --> PRESS OK')
                    file = filedialog.askopenfilename()#manual path to file if default path doesn't exist
                    try:
                        dataFrame = pds.read_excel(file)
                        break
                    except FileNotFoundError:
                        write_err_log()
                        continue
            df_bool = []
            for Amount in dataFrame.Amount:
                if  Amount <= 0: 
                    df_bool.append(True)
                else:
                    df_bool.append(False)                  
            if True in df_bool:
                while run_cycle == True:
                    today = datetime.now()
                    clock_time = today.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
                    date = today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
                    weekday = datetime.today().strftime('%A')
                    Email_adress = os.environ.get('email_user')
                    Email_password = os.environ.get('email.password')
                    empty_stock = dataFrame.loc[dataFrame.Amount <= 0]
                    try:
                        with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587) as server:
                            server.ehlo()
                            server.starttls()
                            server.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
                            server.set_debuglevel(1)
                            server.login(Email_adress,Email_password)
                            subject = 'no-reply'
                            body = f"""Row no.:{empty_stock}\nPart (s) is out of stock\n
                            Date: {weekday} {date}\n
                            Time: {clock_time}
                            \n\n\nThis was an automatically generated message.\nDo not reply to this message!
                            """
                            msg = f'subject:{subject}\n\n{body}'
                            server.sendmail(Email_adress,Email_adress, msg)
                            server.quit
                    except smtplib.SMTPException as error:
                        write_err_log()
                        count +=1
                        if count <= 5:
                            continue
                        elif count >= 6:
                            messagebox.showerror(title='error',message= 'ERROR'+str(error)+"'.",
                            detail=traceback.format_exc())
                    break                                                                  
    def __init__(self):#adds Threading to loop
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.send_stock_data)
            t.start()
class progloop():
    def prog_loop (self):
        progress.pack_forget()
        while run_cycle == True:
            get_stock_and_send_mail()
            sleep(48000)
            continue
    def __init__(self):#adds Threading to loop 
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.prog_loop)
        t.start()

def timer(): #Runtime timer
    global sec 
    if run_cycle == False:
        return
    sec += 1
    time['text'] = f'Runtime: {sec} sec'
    time.after(1000, timer)
time = Label(root, fg='black')
time.pack(side=BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: if you need a task run on a regular basis, you should schedule it outside of the program itself (e.g., via cron)

Comment: if you have a task in a larger program, one way to sleep 30-60 minutes, then check if it is time to run. No drift and handles DST.

Comment: The python add-on APscheduler is pretty good for this sort of task.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to actually use a sleep, and time shifting/drifting over multiple days is the problem, what you can do, although not perfectly accurate, is to readjust the sleep time based on current time. Something like :

```
def seconds_since_midnight():
    now = datetime.now()
    return (now - now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)).total_seconds()

def one_day_to(day_time_secs):
    return 86400+day_time_secs-seconds_since_midnight()
```

And using for instance

```
sleep(one_day_to(3600*18))
```

to schedule at *about* 18h00 the next day, without drifting from day to day